# Problem of memory explosion on recursive function

Tags: c, recursion

On my studies, I need to implement Redelmeier algorithm for counting polyominoes.(This is the article if somebody is interests in http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~barequet/poly-papers/math-cs/1981-Redelmeier.pdf)

The algorithm I wrote works great. The "only" problem is when I get to numbers of over 15 elements(The parameter of the function is GraphSize), I see on the diagnostic tool that the memory of the program takes over 2 GB and then get read access problem.
I wanted to send pointer so The memory won't get allocate all over every recursion, and for what I understood that is what I did.

Where is my mistake?

```
typedef struct node {
    Cell value;
    struct node* next;
}node_t;

void RemoveNodeFromList(int x, int y, node_t** head)
{
    if (*head == NULL) return;
    if ((*head)->value.x == x && (*head)->value.y == y)
    {
        node_t* temp = (*head);
        (*head) = (*head)->next;
        temp = NULL;
        free(temp);
        free_counters++;
        return; 
    } 

    node_t* current = (*head)->next;
    node_t* previous = (*head);
    while (current != NULL && previous != NULL)
    {
        if (current->value.x == x && current->value.y == y)
        {
            previous->next = current->next;
            free(current);
            free_counters++;
            return;
        }
        current = current->next;
        previous = previous->next;
    }
    return;
}

void PushToEndOfList(node_t* head, node_t* new_node)
{
    node_t* context = head;
    while (context->next != NULL) context = context->next;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    context->next = new_node;
}


void Push(node_t* head, Cell info)
{
    if ((head->value.x) == -1)
    {
        head->next = NULL;
        head->value.x = info.x;
        head->value.y = info.y;
    }
    else
    {
        node_t* newNode = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        malloc_counters++;
        newNode->value.x = info.x;
        newNode->value.y = info.y;
        PushToEndOfList(head, newNode);
    }
}

int* count_polyominos_by_given_size(int** array, int GraphSize, int size, node_t* 
        head_Untried_set, int* counter)
{
    while (!CheckIfListEmpty(head_Untried_set))
    {
        Cell* Element = &(head_Untried_set->value);
        int x = Element->x;
        int y = Element->y;
        RemoveNodeFromList(x, y, &head_Untried_set); //Step 1


        array[x][y] = OCCUPIED; //Step2

        counter[size]++; //step3

        Cell new_neighbors[MAX_NEIGHBORS_NUM];
        if (size + 1 < GraphSize)
        {
            int NumOfNeighbors = LookForValidNeighbors(x, y, array, GraphSize, new_neighbors);
            for (int i = 0; i < NumOfNeighbors; i++)
            {//step 4a
                if (head_Untried_set == NULL)
                {
                    head_Untried_set = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
                    malloc_counters++;
                    if (head_Untried_set == NULL) return NULL;
                    head_Untried_set->value.x = -1;
                }
                Push(head_Untried_set, new_neighbors[i]);
            }
            //step 4b           
            counter = count_polyominos_by_given_size(array, GraphSize, size + 1, head_Untried_set, counter);

            for (int i = 0; i < NumOfNeighbors; i++)
            {
                //step 4c
                RemoveNodeFromList(new_neighbors[i].x, new_neighbors[i].y, &head_Untried_set);
            }
        }
        RemoveCell(x, y, array);
        RemoveNodeFromList(x, y, &head_Untried_set);//step 5
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the full implementation? A working example? I see `Cell new_neighbors[MAX_NEIGHBORS_NUM];`. How large is `Cell` and `MAX_NEIGHBORS_NUM`? You might try to visually track the calls to `malloc` and `free`, it might give you a clue....

Comment: Cell is two int parameter struct, and MAX_NEIGHBORS_NUM is four.

Comment: All right; well, add printouts to track memory de-/allocation and run for small sizes to see how the algorithm behaves. Might give you a clue.

Comment: My mistake was actually setting pointer to null before free.
Now I have a problem that after i return from recursive I get garbage value instead of null.